# Using Apply to get around loop

Tags: r

How would I use apply or a version of it to get around using this loop:

```
data<- seq(from = -100, to = 100, by = 10)
data
times<- seq(from = 25, to = 100, by=25)
for(i in 1:length(times))
{
  print(length(data[data < -times[i] | data > times[i]])/length(data))
}
```

I am calculating a frequency table of the "data" dataframe.

Thank you.

Comment: From your verbal description, it sounds like you're looking for `table`

Answer (score 2):

Here is a vectorized solution:

```
unname( #remove names
  rev( #reverse order
    cumsum( #cumulative sum
      rev( #reverse order
        table( #contingency table of the counts of each interval
          cut(abs(data), c(times, Inf)) #cut into intervals
          ) 
        )
      )
    )
  ) / length(data)
#[1] 0.7619048 0.4761905 0.2857143 0.0000000
```

Note that `data` is not a data.frame.